# How to disable programmatically button by using xml button

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, for-loop

i have 4 button create in programmatically button in for loop, is it possible to disable the onclicklistener function or ontouchlistener function by using button create in xml ? Sorry for my einglish, wish can be understand my question.

### Sample Image

[image]

### Code

```java
public class Tab1 extends Fragment {

    TextView textView, test1;
    Button button, button2;
    LinearLayout rl;

    //Overriden method onCreateView
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View h = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab1, container, false);
        //Returning the layout file after inflating
        //Change R.layout.tab1 in you classest
        textView = (TextView) h.findViewById(R.id.textView);
        test1 = (TextView) h.findViewById(R.id.test1);
        button = (Button) h.findViewById(R.id.button);
        button2 = (Button) h.findViewById(R.id.button2);
        rl = (LinearLayout) h.findViewById(R.id.tlayout);

        for (int i = 1; i < 5; i++) {

            final Button btnAddARoom = new Button(getActivity());
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params;
            params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams
                    (ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

            btnAddARoom.setText("Add");
            btnAddARoom.setLayoutParams(params);
            rl.addView(btnAddARoom);


            btnAddARoom.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    test1.setText("qweqweqweqwe");
                }
            });

            button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    btnAddARoom.setOnClickListener(null);
                }
            });
            button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    test1.setText("111111111111111");
                }
            });
        }


        return h;
    }
}
```

Comment: try looking at the View API setEnabled(bool) may point you in the right direction.

Comment: One click, you want to disable all the buttons?

Comment: yes, one click disable all the button create by for loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add all the buttons you created from the for loop into an array.

```
ArrayList<Buttons> buttons = new ArrayList<Buttons>();

for(int i =1 ; i<5 ; i++) {

    final Button btnAddARoom = new Button(getActivity());
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params;
    params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams
            (ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

    btnAddARoom.setText("Add");
    btnAddARoom.setLayoutParams(params);
    rl.addView(btnAddARoom);

    buttons.add(YourDynamicallyCreatedButton)
}
```

Now in your onClick of xml button:

```
onClick(){
   for(Button button: buttons){
      button.setEnable(false)
   }
}
```

Note:

When we add a view(button or text..) via xml we give it an **id**. We can access these elements with this ID. Similarly, when we create buttons dynamically, we need to set id to the buttons/views.

Comment: thanks, may i know how to add all my for loop to list?

Answer (score 0):

Call `setEnable(false)` on your `Button` reference

Example:

```
Button b ;
..
..
b.setEnable(false);
```

Comment: actually i used this btnAddARoom.setOnClickListener(null);, it work out side the onclicklistener method but can't work in onclicklistener method

Answer (score 0):

Keep reference of your programatically added buttons:

```
Button[] buttons = new Buttons[5];
for(int i =0 ; i<buttons.length ; i++) {
    buttons[i] = new Button(getActivity());
    final Button btnAddARoom = buttons[i];
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params;
    params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

    btnAddARoom.setText("Add");
    btnAddARoom.setLayoutParams(params);
    rl.addView(btnAddARoom);
    btnAddARoom.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            test1.setText("qweqweqweqwe");
        }
    });

    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            btnAddARoom.setOnClickListener(null);
        }
    });
    button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            test1.setText("111111111111111");
        }
    });
}
```

Now when you want to disable these buttons:

```
private disableButtons() {
    for(int i=0;i<buttons.length;i++) {
        buttons[i].setEnabled(false);
    }
}
```

Hope it will help you!

Answer (score 0):

If you have a dedicated parent for the four buttons then you can eliminate the Arralist or array.

```
  LinearLayout ll = ..//your linear layout or any other parent
    final int childcount = ll.getChildCount();
    for (int i = 0; i < childcount; i++) {
        View view = ll.getChildAt(i);
        if (view instanceof Button) {
            view.setEnabled(false);
        }
    }
```

Comment: thanks, may i know where should i put this command? is it inside my for loop looping the button?

Comment: Just copy and paste above code on your `DISABLE` button click listner

Comment: it get the error /AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                   java.lang.ClassCastException: android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView cannot be cast to android.widget.Button
                                                                                       at net.simplifiedcoding.androidtablayout.Tab1$2.onClick(Tab1.java:63)

Comment: it occurs at this command line  View button = (Button)rl.getChildAt(i);